# jq - combine multple lines into single comma separated line

Tags: json, csv, jq

I need the IP output below to be printed in a single line like this "10.88.4.92", "10.88.5.203", "10.87.5.215"

```
cat ec2.json | jq ".[] | .private_ip"

"10.88.4.92"
"10.88.5.203"
"10.87.5.215"
```

How to achieve this with jq

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `@csv`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
< ec2.json jq -r "[.[] | .private_ip] | @csv"
```

Comment: I learned to love putting the input redirection at the beginning of the line when working with `jq` ;)